# Emails not looping on Google Sheet when sending them to third party platform

Tags: loops, email, zapier

I'm running a Python code which retrieves email addresses of contacts. I'm sending those contacts to a Google Shee, where I cross-check if they already exist on a list of pre-identified companies by running a formula. If they don't exist on that sheet, I want to send them to a Marketing Automation system. The process up to this point is working fine, however, when I get to the point where I want to send all the contacts under the company to the automation platform, what is happening is that only the first contact under a company is going through. I'm trying to find a way to loop the process of sending multiple contacts from google sheets to the automation system. Any suggestions?

-Checked if the code is sending an array(Multiple contacts) and it is.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you're looking for, you'd have to use [Webhook Triggers](https://zapier.com/help/triggers/#timing-and-precision-of-webhook-triggers), but if only the last row added is being sent through Zapier it means that it's operating in a [polling basis](https://zapier.com/help/triggers/#polling-triggers).

A workaround I used previously and you can try is the following:

1. Add column to Sheets called "State", which will have two states: 'New' and 'Copied'
2. Python script inserts one row with state 'New' and only if previous row (last row) is with state 'Copied'
3. Create another Zap that will update the corresponding row state to 'Copied', when new contact added